# Align block to the right margin, but maintain floating left of items

Tags: css

Here is what I see from the snippet, you may see it differently depending on your device:

[image: blocks]

**UPDATED:** What I want to achieve is this:

[image]

Using only CSS I want the blocks to float like the left panel, but have all the block in the right panel to hit the right side.

```css
.container {
    background-color: wheat; 
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
}

.right {
    text-align: right;
}

ul {

    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {

    border: 4px solid grey;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
                 <ul>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
             <li>four</li>
             <li>five</li>
             <li>six</li>
             
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="inner right">
         <ul>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
             <li>four</li>
             <li>five</li>
             <li>six</li>
             
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You want the blocks to wrap from right?

Comment: Your request is unclear. Would you like your `li` to *float* on the **right** of the panel but the contained text *aligned* on the **left** of the `li`?

Comment: @RedBreast I have added a further image to show what I would like to achieve.

Comment: I've looked at this several different ways (including `flexbox`) and I suspect it's not possible within bounds of pure CSS. I think JS is required. This just isn't the way the box-model works.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I'm coming to the same conclusion, cannot see a pure CSS way!

Answer (score 0):

like this?

if so, add `text-align: left;` to your ul

```css
.container {
    background-color: wheat; 
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
}

.right {
    text-align: right;
}

ul {

    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align:left;
}

li {

    border: 4px solid grey;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
                 <ul>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
             <li>four</li>
             <li>five</li>
             <li>six</li>
             
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="inner right">
         <ul>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
             <li>four</li>
             <li>five</li>
             <li>six</li>
             
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's actually the point of the `.right` class, not doing that.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants as they say _Using only CSS I want the blocks to float like the left panel, but have container flush to the right panel._.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Sorry that i am not good at english. whats the meaning of container flush to the right panel?

Comment: @Andrew No worries, I'm not 100% sure myself but I believe the OP wants the `li` aligned to the left (like in the first box) but the `ul` itself aligned to the right (so there would be a gap to the left of the `ul` not the right).

Comment: @HiddenHobbes after reading it 10 times more, I still dont get it :( I guess we will wait someone to solve it :)

Comment: I attached an image to show what I am looking for see update

Comment: @Neil, your image almost looks the same as my result... you want the space in the ul ?

Comment: Yes exactly! I want it like yours but with the container of the blocks on the right to be touching the right side, therefore when you change size of viewport it always has block on the right staying right, and gap between middle and blocks will get larger as it does after first blocks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `text-align:left;` to your li instead.

EDIT: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6xukrxw/)